# Let $v$ and $w$ be distinct vertices in the complete graph $K_n$ fro $n\ge2$. Prove the number of paths form $v$ to $w$ is...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $v$ and $w$ be distinct vertices in the complete graph $K_n$ for $n\ge2$. Prove the number of paths from $v$ to $w$ is:
\begin{align*}
(n-2)!\sum_{k=0}^ {n-2} \frac{1}{k!}\\
\end{align*}

- We're currently learning about proofs by contradiction, although I am unsure as to how this can be used in this problem, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Proof by contradiction doesn't really work here.  Instead, consider breaking down the number of paths connecting $v$ and $w$ based on the length of the path.  The shortest that a path can be is length $1$, in which there is only one possibility; the longest is length $n-1$, in which we start at $v$, visit all vertices of the graph OTHER than $w$, then go to $w$.  The number of ways to do this is just the number of ways to choose the order in which the remaining vertices are visited, namely $(n-2)!$.

If you can count the number of paths this way, you will get a summation in terms of $\ell$, the length of the paths in question.  You can relate this to the above sum by considering how many vertices OTHER than $v$ and $w$ are involved in a path of length $\ell$.